# Highcharts: custom datalabel for bar chart. Format in PlotOptions not working

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to display data in my rails app. A picture speaks a thousand words...

[image]

Basically I am trying to get the y axis labels to be the bar chart datalabels and concatenate with the value....

So for the first bar, the datalabel would be "idiopathic pulmonary fibrosis 37"

The chart is being passed a variable "data" which is an array of objects that you can see in the console (5 objects in total with the attributes, count, name and y).

My plot option set up is this:

```
      plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '{x}',
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'right',
                    color: '#294469',
                    shadow: false,
                    x: -25,
                    style: {"fontSize": "10px", "textShadow": "0px" }
                },
                pointPadding: 0.1,
                groupPadding: 0
            }
        },
```

I can replace the format with '{y}' and that give me the value, but I can't get the string in there. Any thoughts....

Answer (score 4):

You need to use formatter function for datalabels.

```
dataLabels:{
 enabled: true,
 formatter: function ()  {      
  return this.x  +"  "+ this.y;
          }
       }
```

See [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/tPw24/513/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked.

```
                  dataLabels: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return data[this.x].name + " " + data[this.x].y;
                        },
                        enabled: true,
                        align: 'right',
                        color: '#294469',
                        shadow: false,
                        x: -10,
                        style: {"fontSize": "10px", "textShadow": "0px" }
                    }
```

Comment: even you can do so by this.x + " " +this.y  see demo http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/tPw24/513/